# Delphi timer and variable

Tags: delphi

I have a delphi timer that executes code at 200ms. It will store a variable called CurrentShots. What i need to do is store another variable called OriginalShots to detect if CurrentShots has decreased in the same timer.

Is this possible? I can't work out a way to do this without both variables being the same number.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);//200ms delphi timer
var
  OriginalShots, CurrentShots: array [0..MAX_PATH] of AnsiChar;
begin
  timer2.Enabled := false;
  Win32Check(ReadProcessMemory(hProc, pointer(BaseEU + AddrShotsLeft), @CurrentShots, SizeOf(CurrentShots), Read));
  CurrentShots := OriginalShots;//this will ofcourse set both variables to the same value everytime, how can i do this properly?
  if CurrentShots < OriginalShots then
  begin
    //do stuff here
    UpdateOrAdd(Memo1, 13, 'Shots Left: '+string(CurrentShots));
  end;
end;
```

I realise i have not initialised OriginalShots, but i am unsure of how to do so. Basically to begin with CurrentShots will equal OriginalShots until CurrentShots decreases by 1.

So for instance we start at 50. Both variables have 50. A shot was taken CurrentShots will now show 49 and OriginalShots still has 50 therefore i know a shot has been fired. Now if another shot is fired CurrentShots becomes 48 and OriginalShots is 49.

I am reading CurrentShots from memory, which means OriginalShots is read from memory as well.

I hope i have explained myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I wonder at the use of `array of char` for values that - if your problem is accurately stated - are simple integers.

Similarly, if the values are indeeds char arrays, then direct comparison is likely to not work how you expect and intend.  If they are string representations of numbers then I would convert to the actual integer values before any comparison to ensure correct numeric comparison rather than string comparison.

I shall assume that this is your intention.

All that aside, your problem is fundamentally that you are using local variables in an event handler (i.e. function) when the use of those values requires variables that exist independently of the event and the function.

Simply move the declaration of **OriginalShot** to some location outside of the event handler where it can hold a value independently of the processing in the timer event itself (a variable/field of the form that contains the timer would be a good candidate) and initialise it with an appropriate value before starting your timer:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Timer1: TTimer;
   :
private
  fOriginalShots: Integer;    
   :
end;


procedure TForm1.Create(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fOriginalShots := 100;   // Or as appropriate

  Timer1.Enabled := TRUE;
end;
```

In your event you then compare the integer value of **CurrentShots** with the form member **fOriginalShots** and update **fOriginalShots** only when there is a change:

```
var
  CurrentShots: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  iCurrentShots: Integer;

 ...

// NOTE: In your actual code you may need to deal with the possibility that
//        CurrentShots (the array of char) is not a valid representation of 
//        an integer

iCurrentShots := StrToInt(String(CurrentShots));

if iCurrentShots < fOriginalShots then
begin
  // Other related processing goes here ....

  // Save new CurrentShots value in OriginalShots for comparison the
  //  next time the event fires:

  fOriginalShots := iCurrentShots;
end;
```

Also, I notice that your timer event disables the timer but does not appear to re-enable it and wonder if this is intentional ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, the reason for using AnsiChar is because they are a string representation of numbers as you stated. Also the timer disable was intentional. Thanks for the reply, atleast i now have an understanding of how it needs to be done! :)